# Inject controller with resolve parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I'm using angular material (AM) and I want to pass an external controller to $mdDialog.
In AM documentation we create dialog like this :

```
function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog) { ... }
...
$mdDialog.show({
  controller: DialogController,
  templateUrl: 'dialog1.tmpl.html',
  parent: angular.element(document.body),
  targetEvent: ev,
  clickOutsideToClose:true
})
```

As you can see controller is only a function in the current controller that call $mdDialog. I would like to use a external controller.

```
myApp.controller('ElementEditCtrl', function($scope, 
$rootScope, $stateParams, $filter, $state, ElementsService, element, personnes) { ... }
```

As you can see, I have some resolve in params. For the moment i'm using $controller service to instantiate my controller :

```
var ctrl = $scope.$new();
    $controller('ElementEditCtrl', {$scope: ctrl, personnes: EmployesService.get(), element: angular.copy($scope.element)});
    $mdDialog.show({
        controller: ctrl,
        templateUrl: 'FrontEnd/App/views/ElementEditView.html',
        parent: angular.element(document.body),
        targetEvent: ev,
        clickOutsideToClose: true,
    })
```

And I have this error in my browser console :

Error: ng:areq Bad Argument
Argument 'fn' is not a function, got n

I need to use an external controller because I need to open this dialog from different views and I don't want to duplicate the code in every controllers.

Comment: Can you expose a simple plunker that reproduce the same error you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a service and expose this function:

```js
function createDialog($scope) {
  return function() {
    $mdDialog.show({
      scope: $scope.$new(),
      templateUrl: 'some/temmplate.html,
      clickOutsideToClose: true
    });
  };
```

Then just paste the scope of the controller creating the dialog.

Comment: How i pass my  external controller  to my dialog constructor  ?

Comment: In your external controller pass a $scope to createDialog function and then dialog will have access to all scope properties. If you created controller with controllerAs syntax (let say controllerAs: 'vm') you can access it from dialog template with vm. So if you have in you controller this.title = 'My controller' you can access it with vm.title.